# How to properly specify dependency package versions on a deb package

Tags: package-management, dpkg, deb, packaging

I'm trying to build a package that depends on libssl. Here's how my control file looks like:

```
Architecture: i386
Maintainer: Name
Installed-Size: 938
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.7), libncursesw5 (>= 5.5-5~), libssl1.0.2 (>= 1.0.2~)
```

However, I keep getting:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of package:
package depends on libssl1.0.2 (>= 1.0.2~); however:
Package libssl1.0.2 is not installed.
```

When I run `dpkg -l | grep ssl`, I get

```
ii  libssl-dev:i386                           1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.15                           i386         Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - development files
ii  libssl-doc                                1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.15                           all          Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - development documentation
ii  libssl1.0.0:i386                          1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.15                           i386         Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - shared libraries
ii  libwavpack1:i386                          4.75.2-2ubuntu0.2                            i386         audio codec (lossy and lossless) - library
ii  openssl                                   1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.14                           i386         Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - cryptographic utility
```

Do I have to specify the dependency as `libssl1.0.2 (= 1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.15)`? Is there a way to be less specific as it would mean I have to package for almost each distro version in Ubuntu and Debian. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you want the tilde (`~`) in the version numbers?

Comment: Note sure, I thought the tilde was some sort of wild card, e.g., include 1.0.2*

Comment: It's not a wildcard. You wouldn't need a wildcard anyway since you have `<`,`=`,`>`.

Comment: How did it go Pete? If @user535733 comment solved it for you, he may put an answer for this post.

Comment: @user535733 what is it then? I see this in major packages, eg [Focal's python3 dependency on python3.8 >= 3.8.2-1~](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/python3).  But `python3.8~` does not lexically sort before any version of `python3.8` available in Focal... meaning either Focal's dependencies are broken (which they're not) or `~` is interpreted in a special way; eg: a wildcard.

Comment: @PhilipCouling wildcarding version numbers has limited usefulness, and most users will never need to. If you want to consider the tilde (`~`) a one-way (human-readable) wildcard, go right ahead: Apt can give it to you; you cannot give it back to apt.

Comment: @PhilipCouling I think I had plenty of time to elaborate in the past two years, had I wished to. For example, by writing a proper answer (you are welcome to).

Comment: @PhilipCouling `~` is not a wildcard but have special sorting order and it is the case for all other non-alphanumeric characters `+.` that are allowed in the package version. It is documented in the [Debian/Ubuntu developer manual - Package name and version](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debmake-doc/ch05.en.html#name-version): `0.0 < 0.5 < 0.10 < 0.99 < 1 < 1.0~rc1 < 1.0 < 1.0+b1 < 1.0+nmu1 < 1.1 < 2.0`

Comment: @user.dz Thanks! I was really curious about this so raised it as it's own question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/703950/what-does-a-tilde-mean-at-the-end-of-a-dependency-requirement-in-a-deb-file/703959#703959).  Crucially `~` sorts first.  This means that *any* version beginning with `1.0` will sort after `1.0~` as long as that version itself doesn't start `1.0~`.  So while it is not a wildcard, it seems it's sometimes used as one in a rather makeshift way.

Comment: @PhilipCouling Yeah, I started noticing `~`  after PPA were introduced. PPA and external repositories are using at least one tilde, to avoid racing with late versions of the distribution package.

Answer (score 0):

**libssl1.0.2** is not the package **libssl** with version **1.0.2**, but the package with name **libssl1.0.2**.
Your package depends on:

```
libssl1.0.2
```

But the package you have installed is:

```
libssl1.0.0
```

To make your package depend on your installed version (or greater):

```
libssl1.0.0 (>=1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.15)
```

Comment: I agree, it is not same package. As long the version is amended to package.